# Google App Engine Home Page

Tags: google-app-engine

I added like following in `app.yaml`

```
application: mywebfont
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /font/.*
  script: font.py

- url: /
  static_files: html/index.html
  upload: static_files

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

It's working fine in localhost.
After deploy , I can't check my application home page. It's always show `404 not found error`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'upload: html/index.html'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
application: mywebfont
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

    handlers:
    - url: /font/.*
      script: font.py

    - url: /
      static_files: html/index.html
      upload: html/index.html

    - url: .*
      script: main.py
```